# Android maps api show polylines snapped to road

Tags: android, android-activity, maps, polygon, polyline

I am planning to create a app which displays bus lines on a google maps map and I want it to display the paths the buses take. I know about polylines and polygons in google maps, but idk how I can make them snap to the road. Is that possible? Can I just use the Directions API for that?

Comment: You can use the Directions API and specify `transit` as the mode.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/  Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272427/snap-to-roads-android

Comment: So if I would supply the api the start station, the end station and the stations in the middle, would it create a path between the stations? How can I combine the directions api with the maps api I already use in android?